# slide menu using SWRevealViewController

Tags: swift2

I'm new in IOS development and I am having trouble while implementing SlideMenu using SWRevealViewController.
I want to implement the SlideMenu on RecordPage.
My app starts with LoginPage then after successful Login I move to ContactPage then on RecordPage where I want to implement SlideMenu. My question how can I connect the SWRevealViewContoller to RecordPage?
I am connecting the SWRevealController with slidingMenu using "sw_rear" and RecordPage with "sw_front". The rest of code is fine, but it doesn't work when I click on MenuButton on RecordPage.

Comment: please use below my answer it work and i hope also work for you

Answer (score 0):

Please write this code in ContactPage View Controller where you navigate Record_Page View Controller

```
    let sliderMenu = LeftMenuVC(nibName: "LeftMenuVC", bundle: nil)
    let rightVC = RecordPageViewController(nibName: "RecordPageViewController", bundle: nil)

    let left = UINavigationController(rootViewController: sliderMenu)
    let right = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rightVC)

    let swReveal = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: left, frontViewController: right)
    swReveal.rearViewRevealWidth = (view?.frame.width)!/2
    swReveal.bounceBackOnOverdraw = false
    swReveal.setFrontViewPosition(FrontViewPosition.Left, animated: true)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(swReveal, animated: true)
```

IN RECORD_PAGE View Controller in viewDidLoad method write:

```
    let leftSide = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu-icon"), style: .Plain, target: self.revealViewController(), action: #selector(self.revealViewController().revealToggle(_:)))

    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftSide
    navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false     
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
```